# How to convert stings to int/Typecast in MICROSOFT EXCEl

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

ok so I basically want to create an interactive form on an excel spreadsheet such that I can average out a result based on an arbitrary number of inputs,

however it gets tricky becuase user input must be either a yes or no, and becuase not all tests are aplicable to all data types

for example this is the desired output

```
  Test1    Test2    Test3    Test4      %complete
A  yes      no      Yes      no            50%
B  yes                                     100%
C  no       no      no       yes           25%
```

Comment: Do you want true `Integers` or `float/doubles`? An integer can represent a percentage only if it is the non-decimal 'percentage times one hundred with no remainder'. It cannot represent a true percentage since that (by definition) is a decimal number (unless 100%, 200%, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIF() and COUNTA()

```
=COUNTIF(B2:E2,"yes")/COUNTA(B2:E2)
```

This will count all the `yes`es and divide them by the number of cells with values in them.

[image]

---

If your data is populated via formulas that return Yes/No or an empty string then you will need to change the denominator to a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:E2,"yes")/SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:E2<>""))
```

Comment: Thank you it works miraculously!!! HOWEVER if I enter the formula before any data values it gives divide by zero error, which is fine, it just looks ugly, any fix for that?

Comment: Yes wrap it in an IFERROR: `=IFERROR(...,"")` the `...` is where the formula you use goes. @JonDeal

Comment: @Scott Craner, enjoy the weekend... :D